# Programmatically uncheck Show Unzipped Files option for Winzip

Tags: windows, batch-file, winzip

I am in need of setting the  “Show Unzipped Files” under Home > Unzip options to unchecked for the Winzip 16.5 . The default installation of winzip MSI set the “Show Unzipped Files” options as checked .

I have searched for and modified a number of Windows registry setting related to Win-zip in a test lab env. However I am out of luck with this . I looked at the option of customize the WinZip MSI, editing the Property table in the WinZip MSI file I couldn’t find any property related to this option.

I would like to run a script to modify this default functionally . Is there any registry setting corresponding to this option, if so how this be modified ? Can this option be  modified programmatically by changing the win-zip ribbon bar configuration?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.
Sal.

**Problem Solved :**

To uncheck the "Show Unzipped Files" option in WinZip, we would need to create a registry string value named OpenExplFolder in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Nico Mak Computing\WinZip\WinZip and give it a value of "0". If no select is made by the user , OpenExplFolder string value will not exist.

I have made this change in the registry  and tested it out in the lab environment and it work perfectly fine.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? Or C#? This smells of tag spam. If you have a specific Java question, then ask your Java question with your Java code. If you're just fishing for eyeballs, please remove the Java tag. I also have to wonder if this is a SO question at all. It seems better suited for the superuser's site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"fishing for eyeballs"*  I've never fished for eyeballs.  ..They make for great bait though.  ;)

Comment: please write more description for the problem and put some code!

Comment: @Sal007 the problem ppl will down vote this beacause you have to do first your homework. Find  some example. try it by yourself and not expecting that someone will make this work for you. thanks!

Comment: Hi,
To uncheck the "Show Unzipped Files" option in WinZip, had to create a registry string value named OpenExplFolder in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Nico Mak Computing\WinZip\WinZip and give it a value of "0". If no select is made by the user , OpenExplFolder string value will not exist.

I have made this change in the registry  and tested it out in the lab environment and it work perfectly fine.
Sal.